# Same result over again even if using clearstatcache

Tags: php, filemtime

Why even if I clear cache for that file and modify it (by adding a space) `filemtime` stays the same?

```
clearstatcache(true, $file);
// or clearstatcache()

return date("U", filemtime($file));
```

It drives me crazy. I've already tried turning off caching in `.htaccess`.

Files I hit with it are ($file):

```
string '../private_data/Pages/metaData.xml' (length=34)
string 'Data/StaticRoots.php' (length=20)
string '../private_data/CountryISO/CountryInfo.xml' (length=42)
string 'Data/CountryInfo.php' (length=20)
string '../private_data/Lang/Lang_PL.xml' (length=32)
string 'Data/Lang_PL.php' (length=16)
string '/' (length=1)
```

Comment: What's the full code, including the modification?

Comment: Other missing information that might be a clue: is `$file` an ordinary file path, or some kind of URL or wrapper specification? Are you running the code on Linux, Windows, or MacOS? Is the problem specific to this file, or part of the filesystem, or can you reproduce it with any file?

Comment: @IMSoP Ive provided `$file` paths